# How to submit the value of a disabled form field?

Tags: forms, cakephp, disabled-input

This page actually a preview where user can't change anything,that he has given before.I have tried bellow code,

```
echo $this->Form->input('exchange_type', array(
        'disabled' => 'disabled',
        'empty'   => '--Please Select--',
        'options' => array(
            '6' => 'POINT_TO_PRODUCT',
            '7' => 'POINT_TO_GIFT',
            '2' => 'POINT_TO_GAME'
        )
    ));
```

Here field has disabled but it's sending null value to database.I am trying to send actual value that user has been selected.How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how HTML works, values of disabled elements are not being sent.

What you can do is using a hidden field, that's what the form helper automatically does when using for example checkboxes, in order to ensure that there's always a value being sent, as unchecked checkboxes do not submit any value, just like disabled inputs.

The hidden field should have the same name as the actual field, and it should be placed *before* the actual field, that way the hidden value will only be sent in case the following element is disabled.

```
echo $this->Form->hidden('exchange_type');
echo $this->Form->input('exchange_type', array(
    'disabled' => true,
    // ...
));
```

That would pick up the previously POSTed value for both the hidden input and the select input, and the hidden input would be submittable.

See also **[Cookbook > Helpers > FormHelper > `FormHelper::hidden()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::hidden)**

Comment: Isnt this compromising the readonly/disabled state? I would think that this is super error prone and can easily be circumvented by browser dev tools.
Instead people should focus on not posting that value at all, and using/keeping the existing one in the communication layer.

Comment: @mark Depends on whether that is considered to be a threat, it might be worth explaining, but that wasn't really the question. If this isn't a UI only thing, then one could enable the security component if the possibility of changing values is considered problematic, but if that's actually the case, then that sounds like a conceptual problem to me that needs to be solved instead, that is, the endpoint should only accept valid data, no matter at which step it was defined.

Comment: My point is: Why doing this if this can alltogether be done "right". What he wants is completely unnecessary, and therefore also this kind of trick here.